# If $\{P \lor Q\} \land \{Q \implies R\}$ is true, does it follow that $\{P \lor R\}$ is also true?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

If $$\{P \lor Q\} \land \{Q \implies R\}$$ is true, does it follow that
$$\{P \lor R\}$$
is also true?

Here is my attempt, using a truth table:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c|c}
P & Q & R & P \lor Q & Q \implies R & \{P \lor Q\} \land \{Q \implies R\} & P \lor R \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

(Note that $1$ represents a truth value of **True**, while $0$ represents a truth value of **False**.)

Does this conclusively prove my claim?

**Update**

I intentionally did not include the extra column for
$$\{\{P \lor Q\} \land \{Q \implies R\}\} \implies \{P \lor R\}$$
anymore because I could just read off the truth value of the implication from the juxtaposed truth values of the premise and conclusion.

At any rate, I noticed from the truth table that it is **almost** a biconditional, save for the second and eighth rows.  Any idea on where the *conjectured* biconditional breaks down?  =)

Comment: Yes, it does! P or Q is true whenever ((P or Q) and (Q then R)) is true

Comment: One can do it with less typing. How could $P\lor R$ be false? $P$ and $R$ would have to be both false. But then (first expression) $Q$ would be true, which would make $Q\implies R$ false.

Comment: Um.  Does "^" mean "and"?  are you actually asking if "x and y" implies x?  If both (p caret q) and p=>q are true than they are both true, right?  So p caret q is true.  Don't need to test anything about what they *mean* or imply.  It's true because they are both true.

Comment: It fails to be a biconditional because of two rows: $P=Q=1, R=0$ and $P=Q=0, R=1$. In the first case, the conjunction is false because then $Q\implies R$ is false, but then $P\lor R$ is true. In the 2nd case, the conjunction is false because $P\lor Q$ is false, but $P\lor R$ is true.

Comment: Note that your first expression is equivalent to both $\;(\lnot Q \implies P) \land (Q \implies R)\;$ and $\;(\lnot Q \land P) \lor (Q \land R)\;$, which both can be read as $\;P\text{ if }Q\text{ else }R\;$.  That intuitively explains why $\;P \lor R\;$ is true.

Comment: Correction: that previous comment of mine should read $\;P\text{ if }\lnot Q\text{ else }R\;$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your truth table proves the claim.

We can also observe: $P \vee Q$ is equivalent to $\neg P \implies Q$.  With $Q \implies R$, that gives $\neg P \implies R$, which is equivalent to $P \vee R$.

ETA: Regarding your last question, in the first case, a true value of $P$ "conceals" $\neg (Q \implies R)$, and in the second case, a true value of $R$ "conceals" $\neg P$.

Comment: Thanks Brian!  I have updated my original question with some clarificatory details.  Can you comment on my last question please?  =)

Answer (score 1):

It almost proves your claim — it provides all the evidence you need. What you're trying to show is that the following formula is a tautology, true for all values of $P,Q,R$:
$$
((P \lor Q) \land (Q \!\implies\! R)) \implies (P \lor R).\tag{*}
$$
You can either add another column to your truth table for this formula, and confirm that every value is $1$, or you can reason as follows:

The formula (*) is a tautology *iff* for every row of the truth table, the value in the $((P \lor Q) \land (Q \!\implies\! R))$ column is $\le$ the value in the $(P \lor R)$ column. By inspection, that's the case.

There are less tedious ways to prove this. If $(P\lor R)$ is false, then both $P$ and $R$ have to be false; by hypothesis, $Q\!\implies\! R$ is true, so $Q$ has to be false for that to be true; but then $P\lor Q$ is false. So if the premises are true, then $P\lor R$ has to be true too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, Brian!  =)

Comment: You're welcome Arnie

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to prove 
$$
((P∨Q)∧(Q⟹R))⟹(P∨R)\tag1
$$
is a tautology. You'd better do it by Boolean algebra rather than truth table. 
\begin{align}
(1)&\iff(\neg((P∨Q)∧(\neg Q∨R))∨(P∨R))
\\
&\iff((\neg(P∨Q)∨\neg(\neg Q∨R))∨(P∨R))
\\
&\iff((\neg P∧\neg Q)∨(Q∧\neg R))∨(P∨R))
\\
&\iff(\neg P∧\neg Q)∨((Q∨P∨R)∧(\neg R∨P∨R))
\\
&\iff(\neg P∧\neg Q)∨((Q∨P∨R)∧1)
\\
&\iff(\neg P∧\neg Q)∨(Q∨P∨R)
\\
&\iff(\neg P∨Q∨P∨R)∧(\neg Q∨Q∨P∨R)
\\
&\iff 1∧1
\\
&\iff 1
\end{align}
So $(1)$ is a tautology.

We also have following equivalent form
\begin{align}
(P∨R)&\iff((P∨R)∨1)
\\
&\iff((P∨R)∨(Q∧\neg Q))
\\
&\iff(P∨R∨Q)∧(P∨R∨\neg Q)
\\
&\iff(\neg(P∨R)⟹Q)∧(Q⟹(P∨R))
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note: $x \land y$ being true means both $x$ and $ y$ are true.  So let $x = P \lor Q$ and $ (P \lor Q) \land y $ being true means $(P \lor Q)$ is true no matter what the **** P, Q, y are.